# How to uninstall Windows Vista SP2

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Having recently installed Vista SP2, I noticed that the laptop suddenly started to get alot slower. The obviously solution being to uninstall the service pack.
However Ive ran into some issues, I have tried the following guide:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948537

However all three solutions fail!

1. The Service Pack does not appear in the list.
2. I foolishly ran CCleaner to "tidy" up the computer, hence temp does not exist. I now realize that really such applications are utter rubbish and cause more problems than good to just save a few megabytes.
3. There are no previous restore points (possibly removed by Piece Of CrapCleaner?) , except the one prior to service pack installation...which fails.

Please advise!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speed problems can be caused by any of the following:

- malware infections (virus, trojan, adware, rootkit, etc.)
- hard drive issues (physical damage, fragmented files, etc.)
- bad drivers (graphics, chipset, etc.)

I would strongly recommend a full scan of the disk, including a surface scan, to eliminate physical damage.

Then I'd scan for malware. Have a look at ComboFix, Malwarebytes, and SuperAntiSpyware for some options.

Then I'd do a full disk defrag, using Defraggler from Piriform. CCleaner may have caused you pain, but their defrag tool is very good.

Finally, if you haven't found the problem up to this stage, I'd consider an in-place upgrade of your laptop, using a Vista SP2 streamed install disc. This will repair any issues with the system files, and ensure your registry is reasonably fine.

You'd need a defrag after this anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I will do this. However if the slowness was caused after Windows Update, surely I do not need to defrag? Also sorry, but what is a Vista SP2 streamed install disc?

Comment: A major update like SP2 will cause massive fragmentation of your file system, because so many files are replaced. A Vista SP2 streamed disc is a DVD which contains the Vista install, including SP2, so when you install it, you'll have SP2 done at the same time, saving you a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot uninstall SP2, obviously your only option is to reinstall Vista to get rid of this.

However, you should realize that SP2 contains many bug fixes and security updates. So rather than uninstall it, you should probably try to figure out why your computer is slow, and fix the root cause. It might not even have anything to do with SP2...